# MX Record: Which one is used between (Domain and HOST)

Tags: email, dns, gmail, domain

I hosted my email with google.com for my domain, but for better security, I think that changing MX records within domain is better than in the host (cPanel), I tried to change MX records in domain level (name.com), but unfortunately not worked.
Is there any difference to change the MX at name.com or in cPanel? because both provided ability to change MX.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking or indeed trying to achieve. Please can you [edit] your question to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt anyone can definitively answer the question as phrased, as there are too many ways to set it up.

The ony MX record that matters must be changed in the nameservers for your zone - so this will dictate where you change it.    You should note that domain records to not immediately change everywhere when you click the change button (or equivalent) - rather this starts a process which can take a while to complete [ depending on the setup in the DNS, but typically 1 day ]

One of the things you may be able to do is to provide an MX with a higher priority (ie lower number) then the current one, which may, or may not [ depending on your DNS ] encourage the use of the lower MX record.  Remember to remove the old MX record though, or some mail may get misdirected.